# Zero extension of a smooth function

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I come up with the following question when I read the proof of a theorem regarding approximation of Sobolev functions in Evans.

Let $U$ be a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $V\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ be an open set such that 
$
V\Subset U
$ (namely, $V$ is compactly contained in $U$).
Suppose $f\in C^\infty(V)$ and defined $g:U\to\mathbb{R}$ with $g=f$ on $V$ and $g=0$ on $U\setminus V$.

Here is my **question**:

> Do we have $g\in W^{k,p}(U)$?

---

[**Motivation**]
The proof in Evans mentioned at the beginning is as follows. It is unclear to me that why $u^i\in W^{k,p}(U)$ in (3).

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) No, we do not (at least for large $k$), because $g$ is not even continuous in general, but $W^{k,p}$ is contained in the set of continuous functions by the Sobolev embedding theorem.

2) $u^i$ lies in $W^{k,p}$ because it is the convolution of $\zeta_i u\in W^{k,p}$ with the smooth compactly supported function $\eta_{\varepsilon_i}$.

Comment: For all the $W^{k,p}$ in your answer, do you mean $W^{k,p}(U)$?

Comment: Yes I do indeed

Comment: Would you elaborate (2)?

Comment: I mean $W^{k,p}(U)$

Comment: Thank you for you answer. What I don't understand is that why $u^i$ is defined on $U$ and why $u^i\in W^{k,p}(U)$. Should be that in order to do the convolution, the domain of $u^i:=\zeta_iu*\eta_{\varepsilon_i}$ is slightly smaller than $U$?

Comment: $\zeta_i u$ is supported in $V_i$, which is slightly smaller than $U$, and if you take $\varepsilon_i$ veeeeeery small, then the support of $\eta_{\varepsilon_i}$ will also be very small, so that the convolution will be supported in $W_i$ (which is again smaller than $U$). And if you take the convolution of a function in $W^{k,p}(U)$ with a smooth function, then the result is again in $W^{k,p}(U)$ provided that the support of the convolution is contained in $U$.